# Attaching event listeners when using Angular UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm using Angular 1.4.5 with Angular Ui Router, and for text formatting reasons I'm trying to get `addEventListener` to perform a function when a text field is `blur`ed. The problem I'm running into, however, is that on the load state, the element I'm trying to find does not yet exist because it doesn't exist on the template that loaded, so it never attached to the element

Other than editing each and every template so that it loads `initEventListeners()`, or manually adding `onblur` to each element as needed, is there a (preferably Vanilla) way to add event listeners when changing routes or way to trigger the function when navigating between states?

Here's the relevant pieces of JS, the rest is properly strung together with UI-Router and Angular

---

```
function initEventListeners() {
'use strict'
    if (document.contains(document.getElementById('phone'))) {
       document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('blur',  formatPhoneNumber);
    }
 }

 window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';
     runTicker();
     setTimeout(cycleFooterText, 4000);
     initEventListeners();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular directive to use dom manipulation or add listener.
Your directive will init only when your state is loaded so you don't have to worry about dom selection/load, and it's a best practive anyway.

Exemple of a directive that add test to your input value on blur :

html part:

```
<input type="text" add-test>
```

js part:

```
angular
    .module('testApp', []) // init angular
    .directive('addTest', function() {

        // directive options
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: compile
        };

        return directive;

        // use compile instead of link because you don't need to change the listener on scope change
        function compile(elem, attr) {

            var input = elem[0];

            input.addEventListener('blur', formatPhone);

            function formatPhone(e) {
                input.value += 'test';
            }

        }

});
```

check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kc6pofdz/1/

And this guide if you want to learn more about directives: https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with a vanilla approach here simply because this is exactly what angular **directives** are for. If you create a custom directive and bind it to your `#phone` elements, the blur functionality will be attached to your elements automatically.

But, you mentioned not wanting to modify any of your templates, so what I might recommend in that case is calling your `initEventListeners` method inside of a `$viewContentLoaded` callback (docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events)

**Inside a controller for a template with `<input id="phone">` elements**

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', 
function(event){ initEventListeners(); });
```